# Manage rotated moving raster map

Tags: graphics, bitmap, rotation, raster

My application present a (raster) moving map.
I need to be able to show the map rotated base on any given angle.
The program is currently in VC++/MFC but the problem is generic.
I have a source bitmap (CBitmap or HBITMAP) and draw it to the device context (CDC) using StretchBlt.
While this works fast and smooth for angle=0 (and the user can grab the map smoothly with the mouse), this is not the case if I try to rotate the bitmap and then present it (the rotation of the bitmap using SetWorldTransform() or so takes hundreds of miliseconds and this is too slow).

I think that the solution is to be able to relate only to the pixels that currently on the screen and not rotating the original source bitmap - and this is the key.

If someone has experience with similar implementation then it might save me lots of trial and error efforts.
Thanks!
 Avi.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like SetWorldTransform is extremely slow:
http://www.codeguru.com/Cpp/G-M/bitmap/specialeffects/article.php/c1743

And while the other options presented in that article are faster, there are of course other better solutions like this:
http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/g-m/gdi/article.php/c3693/ (check the comments for fixes and improvements as well)

Also here are some non-Windows centric fast rotation algorithms:
http://www.ddj.com/windows/184416337?pgno=11

Note that if you guarantee power of 2 dimensions you can get significant speed improvements.

Comment: In the first article they say: "GetRotatedBitmapNT() This function is specific to NT and will not work on Windows95. It's the simplest and probably the fastest of the three functions listed in this topic. "
So as I understand it they claim that GetRotatedBitmapNT() is maybe the fastest.
But I'll review the other links and update back if I find a breakthrough.
Thanks so far...
Avi.

Answer (score 1):

As follow up to my question and provided answer, let me summarize the following:

1. I used the algorithm mentioned at http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/g-m/gdi/article.php/c3693/.
2. It works and provide pretty good performance and smooth display.
3. There were some bugs in it that I needed to fix as well as simplify the formulas and 
   code in some cases.
4. I will examine the algorithm mentioned at http://www.ddj.com/windows/184416337?pgno=11 to see if it provides some break through performance that worth adapting it.
5. My implementation required using a large source bitmap, so I needed to modify the code so I will not rotate the whole bitmap each time but only the relevant portion that will be displayed at the screen (otherwise performance would be unacceptable).

Avi.